# index.html will execute PHP code

Tags: apache-2.2, php, html

I have a server with suPHP, Apache2 and PHP5.4.

I noticed that a document index.html will execute PHP code, while test.html will not execute PHP code. Of course I do not want that PHP code is executed inside a index.html file.

I do not know where I should look to find the problem. I didn't find a spot in my configuration where I assign the php-handler to some non-*.php-files.

Here is my mods-available/suphp.conf

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
                SetHandler application/x-httpd-suphp
        </FilesMatch>
        suPHP_AddHandler application/x-httpd-suphp

#       suPHP_PHPPath /usr/bin/php
        <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
                SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
#               Order allow,deny
#               Allow from all
        </FilesMatch>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
        suPHP_AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
#       AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source

        <Directory />
                suPHP_Engine on
        </Directory>

    # By default, disable suPHP for debian packaged web applications as files
    # are owned by root and cannot be executed by suPHP because of min_uid.
# Benötigen wir für Nagios3
#       <Directory /usr/share>
#               suPHP_Engine off
#       </Directory>

# # Use a specific php config file (a dir which contains a php.ini file)
#       suPHP_ConfigPath /etc/php5/cgi/suphp/
# # Tells mod_suphp NOT to handle requests with the type <mime-type>.
#       suPHP_RemoveHandler <mime-type>
</IfModule>
```

Here is my mods-available/php5.conf

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    # To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
    # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
    # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
#    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#            php_admin_value engine Off
#        </Directory>
#    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your .htaccess files for the following, as you could have php interpretation turned on there:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

If that doesn't work, do a string search. It more than likely is turned on somewhere.

```
grep -rnw 'web_directory_here' -e "x-httpd-php"
```

If you find the AddType anywhere, remove it.

==

UPDATE: Another place to check is your apache MIME types to make sure that html isn't being set to php. Make sure html isn't on either of the lines below.

```
check in httpd/conf 
application/x-httpd-php phtml php php3 php4 php5 php6
application/x-httpd-php-source  phps
```

Comment: Hello. This was the first I did. There is no .htaccess with AddType in the directory-chain.

Comment: @rinntech - See update, check apache mime types.

Comment: Also check for *DefaultType* and *ForceType*.

Comment: And SetHandler and AddHandler.

Answer (score 0):

You quote your mods-available/php5.conf.  Is your mod_php5 enabled, that is do you have a /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load?  If so, try `a2dismod php5`, as it isn't recommended to have both suphp and mod_php enabled at the same time, at least not globally.  Also try a phpinfo() in your index.html to work out which module is handling the request..